# I'm receiving a 406 error on ajax return

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails so I'm probably messing this up somehow (obviously). I have a form that is sending the submission back to the controller via ajax. The data is getting there and getting into the db. The goal is that on successful submission the data will be returned in an html format that I can then prepend to page without causing a page refresh.

Here's my controller:

```
# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
  def create
   @project = Project.new(params[:project])
   @project.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
      if @project.save
        #format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
        #format.json { render json: @project, status: :created, location: @project }
        render :partial => "projects/project", :locals => { :project => @project }
    else
       format.html { render action: "new" }
       format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

My ajax function looks like this:

```
$('#new_project').submit(function(){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        beforeSend: setHeader,
        url:'/projects',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: $('#new_project').serialize(),
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            parent.jQuery('#cboxClose').click();
        }
    });

    return false;

});
```

And finally, my partial. The partial is part of a loop. The loop works great and there's no problem there. The loop looks like this:

```
  <% @projects.each do |project| %>

      <%= render :partial => "project", :object  => project %>

  <% end %>
```

And the partial looks like this:

```
<section class="project">

  <p class="name"><span>Name: </span> <%= project.name %></p>
  <p class="title"><span>Title: </span><%= project.title %></p>
  <p class="title"><span>User ID: </span><%= project.user_id %></p>
  <article>
    <span>Details:</span> <%= project.details %>
  </article>
  <article>
    <p>Meta:</p>
    <%= link_to 'Show', project %>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project), :data => { :colorbox => true,:colorbox_height => '500px', :colorbox_width => '500px', :colorbox_iframe => true } %>
    <%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
  </article>

</section>
```

So that's it. I thought I was on the right track but the 406 error is throwing me for a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You send ajax request and your application should return javascript (or json) back to browser. But you call "render" and response has html type. So 406 error is.

If you want to render partial after success ajax call you should slightly change your controller (consider using format.js against format.json).

Controller:

```
if @project.save
   format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
   format.js  #render create.js.erb
else
   format.html { render action: "new" }
   format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

And you should create file create.js.erb in directory with views of this controller with something like that:

```
$("div#that_you_wat_to_update").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'projects/project', :locals => { :project => @project }) %>");
```

P.S. If you really want to respond with json, than you should update your ajax call to process the json response, but it's another story.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I haven't got a chance to try this yet, but I have no doubt it will work. Can you explain to me this part: "#render create.js.erb"

You say to have format.js and then you say to make a file called create.js.erb in the views folder of the controller. This confuses me. Does Rails look at the comment #render create.js.erb and know to use that file name instead of format.js? Or does format.js do something? I'm just trying to understand what's happening there.

Comment: So you're definitely right and I'll be giving you the credit for it. 

I'd like to ask you one more question. The javascript doesn't render anything on the page? I see it show up in the network tab in the developer tools but nothing is appearing on the page. Even when I try to append directly to the body or the wrapper nothing happens. No console.log either. I originally had created an ajax call that handled the form processing and sending it to the controller then I learned I could just use remote => true to do the same thing! So I did that and it's still working.

Comment: I know it's working because the network tab shows the create.js.erb file looks like this:

$("body").append("<section class=\"project\">\n\n  <p class=\"name\"><span>Name: <\/span> test<\/p>\n  <p class=\"title\"><span>Title: <\/span>tet<\/p>\n  <p class=\"title\"><span>User ID: <\/span>1<\/p>\n  <article>\n    <span>Details:<\/span> test\n  <\/article>\n  <article>\n    <p>Meta:<\/p>\n    <a href=\"/projects/18\">Show<\/a>\n    <a href=\"/projects/18/edit\" data-colorbox-height=\"500px\" data-colorbox-iframe=\"true\" data-colorbox-width=\"500px\" data-colorbox=\"true\">Edit<\/a>\n");

Comment: ok, it was my fault. i can only have

$("body").html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'projects/project', :locals => { :project => @project }) %>");

otherwise it won't work. I can't even have console.log('hello') in the file or it won't work. :/

Comment: Hey @JasonShultz! Answer to your question in the 1st comment: One of the Rails main principles is "convention over configurations" and this piece of code ("format.js" without direct call of "render create.js.erb") is one of examples of this principle. Action name is "create". So if it's no "render" function in format.js block, Raisl automatically searches file called "create.js.erb" (create is the name of current action, and .js.erb because the format is javascript).

Comment: This principle is widely used in rendering views. For example if your controller "posts" has action "index" without any direct rendering (i.e. "render anything") Rails searhes view to render in "/app/views/posts/index.html.erb"